# Storing a *.png file to a cloud storage through API

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

My java app generates some .png image which i want to store to any cloud storage through java API. I dont want any paid service if possible in free. Not getting a good answer for last 4 hours. Any suggestion?

Comment: Dropbox has a Java API and is free, have you tried it? https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storage doesn't have a free tier, although for only a handful of PNG images you will likely be spending less than $1 per month.

Google Drive, however, is free for the first 15 GB or so (it's shared with your GMail account, your Google+ photos, etc). Google Drive also provides a Java API: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java

Dropbox and S3 also both have APIs and various quantities/time of free storage. If you're just looking to host images, and you're not trying to make money, and you don't need to host that many, you could look into image-specific services. Imgur.com, for example, provides an API.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox and Google Drive could meet your needs. You can download/upload files pragmatically to [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/python) and also to [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/). They have API to do it.

However, if you are really looking for really complete service where you can scale up your data storage until you want, you really want to take a look at Amazon S3. In fact, as far as I know, Dropbox works on the top of Amazon S3 to provide their services.

If you would like to have an idea about how to upload/download a file to Amazon S3, you can take a look to [this](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-hibernate-s3-clickstart) application example. If you want the same thing on Dropbox or Google Drive, there are a lot of examples on Internet. However, on these two providers you need a token to upload files, what I don't like. I prefer the way in which it works for Amazon S3 (just for programming purposes - GUI is better on GD or Dropbox).

Amazon S3 is not totally free, but it is really, really cheap.

Be aware of the network latency between your app and your File storage provider if you don't use the same physical infrastructure.